# Skip rows: Export data from SSIS into excel file

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, ssis-2008

I am trying to export data from a SQL server database into an excel file using SSIS. I want the data to get inserted from the 6th row and 5th row has headers.

[image]

I am able map the header names, in **Excel Destination Editor**, to the SQL table headers, by writing the SQL command:

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A5:EC5]
```

But still, when I execute the package, the data gets inserted from the 2nd row
How can I start the insertion from 6th row?

Any help, to solve this, is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the blank rows to the dataset in OLE DB source in SSIS. I assume that your columns in your database are named Header1, Header2 and Header3. Replace your OLE DB source query with this query:

```
 select ' ' as Header1, ' ' as Header2, ' ' as Header3
 UNION ALL
 select ' ', ' ', ' '
 UNION ALL
 select ' ', ' ', ' '
 UNION ALL
 select ' ', ' ', ' '
 UNION ALL
 select ' ', ' ', ' '
 select Header1, Header2, Header3 from Your_SQL_SERVER_Tabl
```

You may need to cast your columns to varchar if they are of other types.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use "OpenRowset" properties for excel source, go to the properties page for excel source, set the "OpenRowSet" as "$A6:D", then it should solve your problem.

Comment: It's not working for me. Would you mind explain more or provide some more example?

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar issue trying to export to Excel from SSIS. I ended up going the third-party route by purchasing the "Export Excel Task" from ZappySys. It allows you to specify the cell offset to start at.