# SSIS - Destination excel does not show up all the cells but only F1, F2 etc

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

I am trying to export SQL data into template excel using SSIS. My template looks as below:

[image]

My SQL code returns data as:

[image]

In SSIS in the excel destination not all the columns of my template are showing in the 'Column mapping' section. I can only see 'F1, F2, F3..' in the setting section. Screenshot as below:

[image]

Why are the cells A7, B7, C7,..etc are not showing in the column mapping section? any help on how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

In the [Excel destination editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/excel-destination?view=sql-server-ver15#static-options), use Change the Access mode to `SQL Command` and use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A6:D6]
```

*Where `A6` is pointing to the 6th row where columns header are located and `D6` is that cells where the last column header is located (`D` > column index, `6` > 6th row)*

This will solve the column header problem, but it will still insert data from the first row, there are many workarounds provided in the following topic:

- [Skip rows: Export data from SSIS into excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773596/skip-rows-export-data-from-ssis-into-excel-file)